# Convert String to Decimal in Dynimc json

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a dynamic `json` string:

```
[{
  "Id": "1",
  "Description": "Scenario 1",
  "fc": "-45156,60000",
  "fci": "-45156,60000",
  "fcii": null,
  "fciii": null,
  "fciv": null,
},
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Description": "Scenario 2",
  "fc": "-45156,60000",
  "fci": "-45156,60000",
},
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Description": "Scenario 3",
  "fc": "-45156,60000",
  "fci": "-45156,60000",
  "fcii": null,
},
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Description": "Scenario 4",
  "fc": "-45156,60000",
}]
```

is it a good idea to search in `json` object for string that contains `,` an idea

```
    public decimal ConvertToDecimal(string s)         
    {             
        if (s.Contains(','))             
        {                 
            return decimal.Parse(s.Replace(',', '.'));             
        }             
        else                  
            return SomeDecimalValue;         
     }
```

How I can parse the string to Decimal and keep the decimal separator?

Comment: No, it is a good idea. Good idea is, to use decimal try parse. 
decimal output;
decimal.TryParse("123", out output);

Comment: I can tell yo a sudo, 
if("123".contains(','))
split, and tryparse each one of them
else
try parse the result

Comment: That's a very, very bad idea. JSON has separate notation for strings and decimals. `"-45156,60000"` isn't a decimal. `-45156`, `60000` and `-45156.6` are decimals. If you want to serialize coordinates or value pairs, use proper JSON notation - either an object or array

Comment: What does "keep the decimal separator" mean? You know that the type `decimal` doesn't have a separtor at all, and only the string representation based on the current culture will display a seperator? eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/lWBd6D

Comment: @MuhammadBashir and then you'll have to deal with incorrect decimal and thousand separator interpretations. JSON already has valid ways of specifying numbers and values, so people don't have to split and parse

Comment: What are `fc` and `fci` supposed to contain? One value or two? If that's meant to be a decimal, why is it a string instead of a number? The real solution here is to use a good JSON format, not try to recover from a bad and ambiguous format

Comment: Besides, that `ConvertToDecimal` is already broken. Different cultures use different formats and using the wrong one will result in bad values. Who said `,` is a decimal separator here? The problem can't be fixed by arbitrarily replacing separators. If you want to parse numbers using a specific locale, pass it to `Parse` as a `CultureInfo` anyway, eg `decimal.Parse(str,CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"))`. You *have* to know what the correct locale is though. Otherwise you'll end up with `-4515660000`

Comment: If you replace `,` with `.` and your code runs outside China and the countries around the Pacific, `decimal.Parse` will produce `-4515660000`. If it wasn't for Chine one could say that in most of the world, what you did would produce the wrong result

Comment: this is the output of the json, I cannot change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

```
    var jArr = JArray.Parse(json);

    foreach (var item in jArr)
    {
        foreach (var prop in ((JObject)item).Properties())
        {
if (prop.Name=="Id" || prop.Name=="Description") continue; //you can remove it
            var val = ConvertToDecimal((string)prop.Value);
            if (val != null) prop.Value = val;
        }
    }

      json = jArr.ToString();

public decimal? ConvertToDecimal(string s)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        if (decimal.TryParse(s.Replace(',', '.'), out var val))
            return val;
    return null;
}
```

Since nobody knows what value fc is - is it one number, or two you can change ConvertToDecimal accordingly.

Or you can deserialize it using c# class

```
List<Forecast> forecast= jArr.ToObject<List<Forecast>>();

public class Forecast
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Extra { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the decimal separator to `,`, You can rewrite the convert method as follows:

```
public decimal? ConvertToDecimal(string s)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        return null;
    return Decimal.Parse(s, culture);//#,#
}
```

add reference to [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

**APPROACH 1: The Easy way**

```
public class Converted
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? fc { get; set; }
    public decimal? fci { get; set; }
    public decimal? fcii { get; set; }
    public decimal? fciii { get; set; }
    public decimal? fciv { get; set; }
}

//from: https://json2csharp.com/
public class Root
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string fc { get; set; }
    public string fci { get; set; }
    public string fcii { get; set; }
    public string fciii { get; set; }
    public string fciv { get; set; }

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013442/convert-string-to-decimal-retaining-the-exact-input-format
    public Converted Convert() {
        return new Converted()
        {
            Id = Id,
            Description = Description,
            fc = ConvertToDecimal(fc),
            fci = ConvertToDecimal(fci),
            fcii = ConvertToDecimal(fcii),
            fciii = ConvertToDecimal(fciii),
            fciv = ConvertToDecimal(fciv)
        };
    }

    public decimal? ConvertToDecimal(string s)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            return null;
        return Decimal.Parse(s, culture);//#,#
    }
}
```

usage:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Globalization;

string json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);
List<Converted> ideal = new List<Converted>();
obj.ForEach(x =>
{
   ideal.Add(x.Convert());
});
Console.WriteLine(ideal.Count);
```

**APPROACH 2: The Ideal way**

Roll your own custom `JsonConverter`

```
public class Converted
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(NiceDecimalConverter))]
    public decimal? fc { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(NiceDecimalConverter))]
    public decimal? fci { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(NiceDecimalConverter))]
    public decimal? fcii { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(NiceDecimalConverter))]
    public decimal? fciii { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(NiceDecimalConverter))]
    public decimal? fciv { get; set; }
}

//from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30083923/223752
public class NiceDecimalConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public decimal? ConvertToDecimal(object o)
    {
        string s = Convert.ToString(o);
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            return null;
        return Decimal.Parse(s, culture);//#,#
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var d = (decimal?)value;
        if (!d.HasValue)
        {
            writer.WriteValue("null");
        }
        else
        {
            var niceLookingDecimal = d.ToString().Replace(".", ",");
            writer.WriteValue(niceLookingDecimal);
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return ConvertToDecimal(reader.Value);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(decimal?);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Converted>>(json,new NiceDecimalConverter());
Console.WriteLine(obj.Count);
```